# Javascript Regular Expression fail

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a very basic problem with a regular expression in Javascript, I'm stuggling to get it working.

It want to remove

```
<text id="toto2" class="classTest">useless</text>
```

in the following String:

```
<svg><text id="toto"></text><text id="toto2" class="classTest">useless</text></svg>
```

So, here is my code:

```
var svgStr = '<svg><text id="toto"></text><text id="toto2" class="classTest">useless</text></svg>';
svgStr = svgStr.replace(/<text(.)*?class="classTest"(.)*?>(.)*?<\/text>/gm, '');
alert(svgStr);
```

It only prints:

```
    '<svg></svg>'
```

(it is removing all the < text > nodes).
I really do not understand what I'm doing wrong here, any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using RegEx to match DOM elements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Comment: I know it could sound a bit silly, but in my case it is much simplier, as I receive data as Strings, not as DOM elements (I know I could create DOM elements from the Strings, but I prefer not to do it).

Comment: `var el = document.getElementById('toto2'); el.parentNode.removeChild(el);`

Comment: @tkone, sorry but I don't think so, and thanks for the '-1' thing.

Comment: @Vaat666 I didn't downvote -- voting to close DOES NOT cause a downvote to register.  Entirely different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what your regex is doing:

- Okay, look for `<text`... found it (in `<text id="toto">`).
- Now match everything up to the first time I find `class="classTest"`, okay good, found that (in `<text id="toto2" class="classTest">`)
- Next find everything up to the next `>`, well that's literally right there (after `class="classTest"`)
- Finally, find everything up to the next `</text>`, found it right before `</svg>`.
- Remove all of the match.

So it's starting the match at the first `<text`, ie. the first node, and ending it at the first `</text>` after `class="classTest"`, which is the last node. In other words, removing it all.

Try this:

```
/<text[^>]+?class="classTest"[^>]*>.*?<\/text>/g
```

Comment: Works perfectly, and you explained me clearly what my actual regexp tried to do. A big thank you!

Comment: This is a good answer. As a string, it could match `<textxyz class="classTest"> ... </text>`. Unlikely though. `\s` or `(?=\s)` might fix that.